# MFC: How does a FrameWnd know when a docked pane is resized?

Tags: mfc

I have a `CFrameWndEx` with several docked `CDockablePanes` but I can't seem to get notified when the size of the docked pane is changed (so I can resize my other windows accordingly).  Tried Spy++ to check for messages, but custom draw seems to be the only one (which doesn't seem appropriate) and also tried overriding RecalcLayout, but that is not called under this circumstance.  `OnSize` doesn't work because the size of the frame itself is not changed.  Any ideas?

(Ps: I'm pretty sure it's possible because I used to have a splitter window as the 'client' area, and it would resize itself magically when the panes were resized)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK this is a bit weird, but I had the exact same question, searched on Google, then saw that I had answered this question over a year ago but completely misunderstood what the question was about :)

Anyway for reference of future Google using people, the answer to this question is to override virtual void CFrameWndEx::EAdjustDockingLayout(HDWP hdwp) and do any resizing of client controls there. To get the client area after the hiding/closing/whatever of panes, use m_dockManager.GetClientAreaBounds(). My AdjustDockingLayout looks like this (m_View is the child window that is supposed to fill the whole client area regardless of the state of any docking panes, adjust as needed):

```
void CMainFrame::AdjustDockingLayout(HDWP hdwp)
{
    CFrameWndEx::AdjustDockingLayout(hdwp);

    if (m_View.GetSafeHwnd()) {
        CRect rectUsable = m_dockManager.GetClientAreaBounds();
        m_View.MoveWindow(rectUsable);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a definite improvement over what I've got now, and solves the specific problem described (that of notification).  However the code as shown here doesn't work in my app because it 'feels' like the docking manager hasn't 'settled' yet at the point this is called.  So when I dock a toolbar inside the main window, it doesn't draw correctly.  If I separate the GetClientAreaBounds and the MoveWindow into a timer callback triggered from this function, then it 'works'.

Comment: I had some redrawing issues as well, in my case removing WS_CLIPCHILDREN from the CDockablePane in which the panes reside solved it. Basically in my CMainFrame::OnCreate, I do the following:  DockPane(&m_Pane1);
CDockablePane* pTabbedBar = NULL;
m_Pane2.AttachToTabWnd(&m_Pane1, DM_SHOW, TRUE, &pTabbedBar);
pTabbedBar->ModifyStyle(WS_CLIPCHILDREN, 0);

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the 'content' of the CFrameWndEx is itself a window, and in that window live the 'main content' windows. Check with Spy++ for the window hierarchy and if any of the child windows of the CFrameWndEx (other than the dockable panes) do get message when they are resized. Basically when docking panes are docked, the CFrameWndEx resizes its children, so you'd have to detect it there and (if required) reflect the message back to the CFrameWndEx if that's really where you need it.

Alternatively, maybe I'm misunderstanding and is what I described exactly what you're trying to do. In that case, I think there is something wrong with the way you add your window to the CFrameWndEx since that should handle the resizing itself. Is the parent of the child window set correctly to the CFrameWndEx when you create it?